# MOSFET - Body Diode protection

Tags: mosfet, body-diode

I want to build the cricuit like on the image below:
[image: Circuit Image]

- V1 - Is a 14S LiPo battery(there would be fuse in real life between
  positive battery terminal and "BATTERY+"
- M1 - PMOS acting as a load switch
- LOAD - Place where the load should be(DC Motor controller)
- CTRL - pin turning the LOAD on/off

---

Q. What would happen if by mistake higher voltage than the battery would be connected where the LOAD is? I assume M1 Body diode would conduct causing overheating and potentialy burn the M1.

Comment: And the other problem is that your PMOS needs a VGSmax of -48V

Comment: Sure, the Zener diode should be placed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I assume M1 Body diode would conduct causing overheating and
> potentially burn the M1*

[image]

Yes it could.